RecyclerView repite los elementos al girar la pantalla o pasar de fragmento
Soy novato en programación, estoy realizando una aplicación en Android Studio en Kotlin con fragmentos sincronizado con la plataforma Faribase, lo cual en un fragmento estoy realizando un RecyclerView y Adapter para ser una lista de páginas, todo se ejecuta bien, pero al momento de girar el celular de vertical a horizontal o de salir del fragmento y volver se duplican los elementos. No se cual es el error si me pueden ayudar, creo que el error esta en el adapter.
class ShareFragment : Fragment() {

    private lateinit var shareBinding: FragmentShareBinding
    private lateinit var shareViewModel: ShareViewModel
    private lateinit var shareAdapter: ShareAdapter
    private var shareVehicle: ArrayList<PaperworkServer> = ArrayList()

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View {
        shareBinding = FragmentShareBinding.inflate(inflater, container, false)
        shareViewModel = ViewModelProvider(this)[ShareViewModel::class.java]
        return shareBinding.root
    }

    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
        shareViewModel.loadShareFromServerDone.observe(viewLifecycleOwner) { result ->
            onLoadChareFromServerDoneSubscribe(result)
        }

        shareViewModel.loadPaperworkServer()

        shareAdapter = ShareAdapter(shareVehicle, onItemClicked = { onShareItemClicked(it) })

        shareBinding.shareView.apply {
            layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this@ShareFragment.requireContext())
            adapter = shareAdapter
            setHasFixedSize(false)
        }
    }

    private fun onShareItemClicked(share: PaperworkServer) {
findNavController().navigate(ShareFragmentDirections.actionShareFragmentToLinkTwoFragment(share))
    }

    private fun onLoadChareFromServerDoneSubscribe(shareServerLoaded: ArrayList<PaperworkServer>) {
        shareVehicle = shareServerLoaded
        shareAdapter.appendItems(shareVehicle)
    }
}

Adapter
class ShareAdapter(
    private val shareList: ArrayList<PaperworkServer>,
    private val onItemClicked: (PaperworkServer) -> Unit
) : RecyclerView.Adapter<ShareAdapter.ShareViewHolder>() {

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): ShareViewHolder {
        val view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(R.layout.card_view_item_share, parent, false)
        return ShareViewHolder(view)
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ShareViewHolder, position: Int) {
        val share = shareList[position]
        holder.bind(share)
        holder.itemView.setOnClickListener{ onItemClicked(shareList[position])}
    }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int = shareList.size

    fun appendItems(newList: ArrayList<PaperworkServer>){
        shareList.clear()
        shareList.addAll(newList)
        notifyDataSetChanged()
    }

    class ShareViewHolder(itemView: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView){
        private val binding = CardViewItemShareBinding.bind(itemView)
        fun bind(share: PaperworkServer){
            with(binding){
                titleLinkTextView.text = share.name
                cardShareTextView.text = share.information
            }
        }
    }
}

ViewModel
class ShareViewModel : ViewModel() {

    val paperworkServerRepository = PaperworkServerRepository ()
    private var shareVehicle: ArrayList<PaperworkServer> = ArrayList()

    val loadPaperworkServer: MutableLiveData<ArrayList<PaperworkServer>> = MutableLiveData()
    val loadShareFromServerDone: LiveData<ArrayList<PaperworkServer>> = loadPaperworkServer

    fun loadPaperworkServer (){
        GlobalScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO){
            val querySnapshot = paperworkServerRepository.share()
            for (document in querySnapshot) {
                val paperworkServer: PaperworkServer = document.toObject<PaperworkServer>()
                shareVehicle.add(paperworkServer)
            }
            loadPaperworkServer.postValue(shareVehicle)
        }
    }

}

pantallazo del funcionamiento
enter image description here
pantallazo del error al girar la pantalla o pasar de fragmento se duplica los elementos
enter image description here
He intentado modificar el adapter pero no logro solucionarlo antes lo empeoro
